# Quartz change MisfireInstruction globally

Tags: java, apache-camel, quartz-scheduler

Is there a way to change for all jobs (CronTrigger) the MisfireInstruction value ?
I tried setting:

```
org.quartz.CronTrigger.misfireInstruction=2
```

in `org/quartz/quartz.properties`

but it does not seem to have effects.

version of quartz used is 1.8.5
with camel 2.10.3

Note that I don't create the quartz trigger myself, it's done via a camel route

```
from("quartz://" + getJobId() + "?cron=" + cronExpression + "&stateful=true")
        .routeId(getJobId())
        .autoStartup(false)
        .to(getRouteTo());
```

so I don't have immediate access to the quartz crontrigger and that's why I would like to change the misfire policy globally.

Answer (score 1):

Quartz JAR has embedded `quartz.properties` file, so not sure which .properties file gets picked up.

On `org.apache.camel.component.quartz.QuartzComponent` you can configure a custom properties file to be used:

```
QuartzComponent quartz = new QuartzComponent();
quartz.setPropertiesFile("classpath:com/foo/myquartz.properties");
```

And then add the component to Camel:

```
camelContext.addComponent("quartz", quartz);
```

Comment: I'm sure my quartz.properties is the one that's taken as it is saved under WEV-INF/classes/org/quartz . I'm more looking for an answer concerning the fact that its possible or not to a general override of the misfire policy with quartz. If not possible what I can do instead of stopping / starting my cron routes is removing and adding them back dynamically.